# Permutation algorithm in the form of

Tags: algorithm, permutation

```
R= repeats allowed -> 2
A= alphabet (1-10)
S= space = 4;
```

So we want  example:

```
[1][1][4][5]
[1][7][4][5]
[5][1][4][5]
```

But need a fancy math formula to calculate this and all combinations ?

Comment: What does "repeats allowed" mean?

Comment: basically, for each permutation  like 1,1,4,5  (1) is repeated twice as per R variable.  anyone (one) item can repeat R times.
sooo 1,1,1,4 is INVALID R > 2

and  1,1,4,4 is also INVALID  cause there is more than one repeat
if this makes any sense !

Comment: Do the repeats have to be contiguous? is 5,1,4,1 allowed if R=2 ?

Comment: @Pete: No they can be anywhere , so 5,1,4,1 is okey ;)

Comment: So just to clarify, with R=2, you can allow at most 2 digits to repeat in total, regardless of which digit? So 1,1,4,4 is invalid because you then first have 2 digits that repeat, using up R=2, and then the two 4's are too much? What about R=3? Is 1,1,4,4 good then? What about R=4? Is 1,1,4,4 good then? You need to be much clearer in your question.

Comment: @Lasse:Sorry my mistake

with R=3 1,1,4,4 is still invalid you can only have ONE repeat and the "nature" of the repeat is describe by R 
so with R=3
1,1,1,4 would be valid.

Will read up on your link, thanks.

Comment: Title say permutations, but body says combinations. Which is it?

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, your alphabet is 1 .. 10, with each 'letter' possibly occurring twice.  So what you really have is an alphabet that is ...

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 10
```

It has a length of 20, not 10.

The problem now becomes 20 permute 4.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
As per your additional comments to your question, you can then check each generated permutation to see if it is of the form XXYY as that would be invalid according to what you have written.

Comment: ahhh it's starting to make sense, thanx :)

Comment: This answer is on the right track, but unfortunately incorrect, since 20 permute 4 assumes all elements are distinct, which they are not.

Comment: my head is going to explode :(

Anyway to calculate the amount of permutation for the above/original values ?

Comment: BlueRaja--you are correct.  Although tempted to delete my answer as it has been properly pointed out how it is incorrect, I will leave it here in hopes that others will learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

The total number is

    <strike>N * [ (S choose 1) * ((N-1) permute (S-1)) 
        + (S choose 2) * ((N-1) permute (S-2)) 
        + ... 
        + (S choose R) * ((N-1) permute (S-R)) ]</strike>

- In otherwords, probably best to fix 1
  of the repeated item in place (`S
  choose 1` different ways of doing
  this) and permute the remaining `N-1`
  items over the `S-1` remaining spaces; (same as normal `N permute S`)
- then fix 2 of your identical item in
  place (`S choose 2` different ways of
  doing this) and permute the remaining
  `N-1` items over the remaining `S-2` spaces.
- etc for each possible number of repeated items, from 1 up to R
- And then there are N choices for
  your possible repeated item.

You can use this algorithm to enumerate the possibilities too.

### Edit

Oh dear.
Thanks @blueraja, you are absolutely correct! the n-repeated-items case does not generalise to 1 item!

corrected formula is therefore

```
(N permute S)
+ N * [ (S choose 2) * ((N-1) permute (S-2)) 
      + (S choose 3) * ((N-1) permute (S-3)) 
      + ... 
      + (S choose R) * ((N-1) permute (S-R)) ]
```

Comment: sorry for multiple edits - got my permutes and chooses muddled!

Comment: This is much closer to a correct answer.  However, notice that the string `1 2 3 4` gets counted four times: once if we consider `1` the fixed element, once if we consider `2` the fixed element, etc...

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but -1 for giving out blunt answer to (what I assume is a) homework problem :)

Answer (score 3):

A correct general answer requires a summation.  I will show you how to do it for these particular values, and let you generalize it.

There are two cases:

- Permutations containing no duplicates.  This is just `10 P 4`
- Permutations containing exactly one duplicate:

  - Choose which number is the duplicate: `10 C 1`
  - Choose two places for it: `4 C 2`
  - Choose the numbers which fit into the remaining two places: `9 P 2`

Thus the answer to this particular case is 9360.

Comment: Excellent :)  Can you also post the math to arrive at 9360 ?

Comment: Comeon Jacques, you can do that part.  Remember, you multiply ANDs, and add ORs *(the two cases are ORed together, but within each case each condition is an AND)*

Answer (score 0):

There are relatively few possible solutions (< 10000), so it should be ok to generate all words in A^4, then remove the words with more than 2 repeats.

**OR**

- Generate the (ordered) combinations of N distinct words
- Generate the permutations of that subset to get all the possibilities without duplicates
- Do the same with N-1 words
- For each element in these words, add a duplicate at all the positions but the position of the said character.

Comment: ja also thought about going a brute force method, but was want a more 'clever' solution, as what about cases where S(Space) = 200 then it becomes imense
but should still be WAYYYYY less than if we allow all repeats

Comment: "Generate the (ordered) combinations of N distinct words" ? ordered ?
 Sorry can you explain more or maybe give example ?Me being dumb :(

Comment: Ordered means words are sorted (w1 < w2 < w3 ...), so 123 is a possibility but 231 isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that only one item can repeat, and this item is not predetermined.

Here is a formula that works on A(alphabet size), S(strings size) and R(maximum repetition count):

**f(A,S,R) = (A perm S) + A*Sum[r=2 to R] ( (S choose r)*(A-1 perm S-r) )**

For example, for R=1 (simple permutation) we get f(A,S,R)=(A perm S) as expected. For A=S=R=2 we have f(A,S,R)=4 which corresponds to:

1,2

2,1

1,1

2,2

The case you describe in the question is A=10, R=2, S=4, and then we have:

f(A,S,R) = 9360

(Exactly as BlueRaja calculated)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html) is a nice article about combinations and permutations, there you can find all the formulas